# How to set parameters in keras to be non-trainable?

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I am new to Keras and I am building a model. I want to freeze the weights of the last few layers of the model while training the previous layers. I tried to set the trainable property of the lateral model to be False, but it dosen't seem to work. Here is the code and the model summary:

```
opt = optimizers.Adam(1e-3)
domain_layers = self._build_domain_regressor()
domain_layers.trainble = False
feature_extrator = self._build_common()
img_inputs = Input(shape=(160, 160, 3))
conv_out = feature_extrator(img_inputs)
domain_label = domain_layers(conv_out)
self.domain_regressor = Model(img_inputs, domain_label)
self.domain_regressor.compile(optimizer = opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
self.domain_regressor.summary()
```

The model summary: [model summary](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWR8q.png).

As you can see, `model_1` is trainable. But according to the code, it is set to be non-trainable.

Comment: Are you sure it is not just a typo? It should be `trainable` not `trainble` (i.e. an `a` is missing before `b`).

Comment: I found out that I miss spelled the Word "trainable" to "trainble", and saddly keras doesn't warn me that the model doesn't have the property "trainble". The question could be closed.

Comment: thanks to others anyway.

Comment: OK just see the typo, anyway just for future reader.

Comment: You may answer your own question if you like and mark it as answered :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a typo in the Word "trainble"(missing an "a"). Saddly keras doesn't warn me that the model doesn't have the property "trainble". The question could be closed.

Answer (score 40):

You can simple assign a boolean value to the layer property `trainable`.

```
model.layers[n].trainable = False
```

You can visualize which layer is trainable:

```
for l in model.layers:
    print(l.name, l.trainable)
```

You can pass it by the model definition too:

```
frozen_layer = Dense(32, trainable=False)
```

From Keras [documentation](https://keras.io/getting-started/faq/):

> To "freeze" a layer means to exclude it from training, i.e. its
>   weights will never be updated. This is useful in the context of
>   fine-tuning a model, or using fixed embeddings for a text input.
>   You can pass a trainable argument (boolean) to a layer constructor to
>   set a layer to be non-trainable.
>   Additionally, you can set the trainable property of a layer to True or
>   False after instantiation. For this to take effect, you will need to
>   call compile() on your model after modifying the trainable property.

Comment: Notice that you can't make `trainable=False` on simply "layers", you must take layers "from the model instance" that you will compile: `self.domain_regressor`. You will probably need recursive layer finding because there are models inside models.

Comment: @DanielMöller You can. `trainable` is the property of the base Layer() class.

Comment: It won't take effect.

Comment: @DanielMöller The main question that it won't effect to what? To the model training or? Be a bit exacter please, however I'm quite open any new knowledge you can provide.

Comment: It will not be really frozen, at least in my experience (maybe newer versions work different). If you don't get the layer "from the exact model" you are compiling, the trainable attribute will not really work.

Comment: I was stuck on this when I was trying to unfreeze layers from a functional model that I have as part of my network. Thanks to @DanielMöller 's comment, I realized I should have made that whole functional layer trainable, freeze all of its layers, then using a function I can unfreeze the layers I want.

Answer (score 9):

Despite the fact that the original question's solution is a typo fix, let me add some information on keras trainables.

Modern Keras contains the following facilities to view and manipulate trainable state:

- `tf.keras.Layer._get_trainable_state()` function - prints the dictinary where keys are  model components and values are booleans. Note that `tf.keras.Model` is also a `tf.Keras.Layer`.
- `tf.keras.Layer.trainable` property - to manipulate trainable state of individual layers.

So the typical actions look like following:

```py
# Print current trainable map:
print(model._get_trainable_state())

# Set every layer to be non-trainable:
for k,v in model._get_trainable_state().items():
    k.trainable = False

# Don't forget to re-compile the model
model.compile(...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the last 3 lines in your code:

```
last_few_layers = 20 #number of the last few layers to freeze
self.domain_regressor = Model(img_inputs, domain_label)
for layer in model.layers[:-last_few_layers]:
    layer.trainable = False
self.domain_regressor.compile(optimizer = opt, loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```