# KERAS: Pretrained a CNN+Dense model. How to freeze CNN weights and substitute Dense with LSTM?

Tags: keras, lstm, conv-neural-network, pre-trained-model

I trained and load a cnn+dense model:

```
# load model
cnn_model = load_model('my_cnn_model.h5')
cnn_model.summary()
```

The output is this (I have images dimension 2 X 3600):

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 3600, 32)       128
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 1800, 32)       3104
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 600, 32)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 600, 64)        6208
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 300, 64)        12352
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_2 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 100, 64)        0
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 100, 128)       24704
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_6 (Conv2D)            (None, 2, 50, 128)        49280
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_3 (MaxPooling2 (None, 2, 16, 128)        0
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 4096)              0
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              4195328
_________________________________________________________________
dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 1024)              1049600
_________________________________________________________________
dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3)                 3075
=================================================================
Total params: 5,343,779
Trainable params: 5,343,779
Non-trainable params: 0
```

Now, what I want is to leave weights up to flatten and replace dense layers with LSTM to train the added LSTM part.

I just wrote:

```
# freeze model
base_model = cnn_model(input_shape=(2, 3600, 1))

#base_model = cnn_model
base_model.trainable = False

# Adding the first lstm layer
x = LSTM(1024,activation='relu',return_sequences='True')(base_model.output)

# Adding the second lstm layer
x = LSTM(1024, activation='relu',return_sequences='False')(x)

# Adding the output
output = Dense(3,activation='linear')(x)

# Final model creation
model = Model(inputs=[base_model.input], outputs=[output])
```

But I obtained:

```
base_model = cnn_model(input_shape=(2, 3600, 1))
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'
```

I know I have to add TimeDistributed ideally in the Flatten layer, but I do not know how to do.
Moreover I'm not sure about base_model.trainable = False if it do exactly what I want.
Can you please help me to do the job?

Thank you very much!

Comment: if you define your basemodel: base_model = cnn_model() instead of base_model = cnn_model(input_shape=(2, 3600, 1))

Comment: I obtain same error:      base_model = cnn_model()
TypeError: __call__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'inputs'

Comment: with: base_model = cnn_model I obtained: ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_1: expected ndim=3, found ndim=2

Comment: At this point I suppose I have to insert TimeDistributed somewhere

Comment: ok this is correct... the shape of your previous model doesn't match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't directly take the output from Flatten(), LSTM needs 2-d features (time, filters). You have to reshape your tensors.

You can take the output from the layer before flatten (max-pooling), let's say this layer has index `i` in the model, we can take the output from that layer and reshape it based on our needs and pass it to LSTM.

```
before_flatten = base_model.layers[i].output # i is the index of the layer from which you want to take the model output

conv2lstm_reshape = Reshape((-1, 2))(before_flatten) # you have to select it, the temporal dim and filters

# Adding the first lstm layer
x = LSTM(1024,activation='relu',return_sequences='True')(conv2lstm_reshape)

# Adding the second lstm layer
x = LSTM(1024, activation='relu',return_sequences='False')(x)

# Adding the output
output = Dense(3,activation='linear')(before_flatten)

# Final model creation
model = Model(inputs=[base_model.input], outputs=[output])

model.summary()
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I have no errors. Just one strange thing. In the final model I have all parameters trainable. Where to put model.trainable = False?

Comment: You told you only want to make your CNN layers frozen, you can iterate each layer and make them non-trainable individually. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53503389/how-to-set-parameters-in-keras-to-be-non-trainable/53503615